# React native router flux - How to access back pressed from navigation bar (not hardware back button) in android?

Tags: android, react-native, back, react-native-router-flux

First of all, I'm very new to react native.
I have used react native router flux for navigation in my project.

Problem:
I want to check if the user has pressed back from top bar(navigation bar). 
I know how to listen to  hardware back button press.

But I cannot figure out how to listen if the user has pressed back from top bar.

I searched for almost everyday possible. But I'm not able to get the solution.

Any suggestions .

Comment: Can you please share your code and your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register your scene as:

```
<Scene 
         key="latest"
         title="LATEST"
         titleStyle={{flex:0}}
         component={Latest}
         onRight={()=>{}} 
         rightButtonImage={NOTIFICATION_ICON}
         onLeft={()=>{}}
         leftButtonImage={NAV_SEARCH_ICON}
/>
```

and then in your componentDidMount() use setParams() as:

```
componentDidMount() {
          this.props.navigation.setParams({
               'onRight': this.showNotifications,
               'onLeft': this.showSearch,
         })
  }
```

and implement showSearch or showNotifications method.

That's it .